# Why is my component not rendering?

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently watching the React Path @ PluralSight (which is excellent by the way) and I'm going through some problems with two components.

I have this component called Authors, which is here:

```
class Authors extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            authors: []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.isMounted()){
            this.setState({ authors: AuthorApi.getAllAuthors() });
        }
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <h1>Authors</h1>
                <hr />
                <AuthorList authors={this.state.authors} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And the component AuthorList, which is here:

```
const AuthorList = (props) => {
    const createAuthorRow = (author) => {
        return(
            <tr key={author.id}>
                <td><a href={"/#authors/" + author.id}>{author.id}</a></td>
                <td>{author.firstName} {author.lastName}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    };
    return( 
        <div>
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.props.authors.map(createAuthorRow, this)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
};
```

The problem is that they're not rendering! They both are inside the same file and somehow they won't render. I have tried making separate files for each of them but they still won't render. Am I missing something?

Comment: open your console developer tools in chrome, and tell us exactly what error it says?

Comment: TypeError: "this.isMounted" is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting any runtime exceptions in the console? As written in your question - you should be - which would be why you are not seeing anything render.

`AuthorList` as implemented here is a stateless functional component. You are referencing `this` within the component - `this` in a functional component references the function, not a React class which would have `props` defined off `this` - props is passed in as an argument - you can reference this directly.

So change

```
<tbody>
    {this.props.authors.map(createAuthorRow, this)}
</tbody>
```

to

```
<tbody>
   {props.authors.map(createAuthorRow)}
</tbody>
```

Also - please check out [this article on the React team deprecating isMounted](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html)
As you noted - this is not a function - along with the suggestion above - remove it. You are already using the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method - fetching results from your backend here at the time this is called is fine for the example you are working with.

Comment: Yes I am, it says that `this.isMounted()` is not a function

Comment: @RenéVidrialesTrujillo - i have updated the answer to address the issue you are having with `isMounted` as well.

Comment: Thanks! I followed your suggestions: got rid of `this.isMounted()` and everything is working fine now. Also, I got rid of the `this` in the stateless component.